# Display size increased after restarting the Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. I was using chrome...suddenly my pc got hung...and then I shut down it, and restart it. but after restarting the display size increased, and now everything is looking bigger...even the content does not fit in a screen size. please help me, how can I set my display size to the default.

Here is screenshot of my desktop, how it looks:

[image: these are screenshots of my desktop, how it looks.]

Comment: Are you talking about your laptop display? Go to Settings > Displays > Resolution. Select a resolution from the list and check if it works. Play with other options as well to get it working.

Comment: Are, I've tried, Go to Settings > Displays > Resolution. it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you tried all the previous things, maybe you have an issue with your HDMI cable connector. Maybe the wire has a defect.

Check the connection or change the wire and see if it works - that fixed the problem in my case.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me... I reconnected HDMI cable and now my display looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have increase your display resolutions. So u can go to setting display and reset it to the optimal display monitor resolution.
Regards

Comment: No, I've tried changing the resolution. but it did not work.